# I have canon Pixma E560 printer.I want drivers for this printer. cannot communicate with printer problem

Tags: drivers, printing

My printer was detected by the OS but when I scan a document it says.. cannot communicate with printer..
I'm planning to install ubuntu as my host machine.. but I use ubuntu as virtual machine for now to see all the drivers are functioning or not...all were working except this printer driver... now I'm confused that if the virtual machine is making the problem of not communicating. or the OS does not have it's drivers.. please help me
and I'm new to linux..

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 20.04.01